# How to reduce time complexity of a C# method with nested loops

Tags: c#, big-o

I am using Kubernetes C# client to patch the deployments in a cluster with by changing the tag of the images in containers with specific image name.

My fist version of the method doesn't seems to be efficient, according to my knowledge having a quadratic time complexity, O(n2).

```
private List<V1Deployment> UpdateImageTag(string imageName, string tag, List<V1Deployment> deployments)
        {
            var updatedDeployments = new List<V1Deployment>();

            if (deployments?.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var deployment in deployments)
                {
                    foreach (var container in deployment?.Spec?.Template?.Spec?.Containers.SkipWhile(x => !x.Image.ToLowerInvariant()
                                                                                                            .StartsWith(imageName.ToLowerInvariant())))
                    {
                        if (container is null)
                        {
                            // Log it and go to the next container.
                            _logger.LogDebug("Deployment {Deployment} has a null container, skipping it.", deployment?.Metadata?.Name);
                            continue;
                        }
                        SetImageTag(tag, container);

                        if (!updatedDeployments.Contains(deployment))
                        {
                            updatedDeployments.Add(deployment);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return updatedDeployments;
        }
```

How this can be achieved in a more efficient way?

Comment: You probably want to change your container check to something once rather than this inelegant `continue`/`contains`  to two statements like (pseudocoding) `if(containersStartingWithImage.Any(container => container != null)) {updatedDeployments.Add(deployment)}` and `foreach( containersStartingWithImage.Where(container => container != null) ) {SetImageTag}`

Comment: Not sure about the logic here - why are you skipping containers and then updating all remaining containers? Also should not `SkipWhile(x => !x.Image` throw if there is container which is `null`?

Comment: I do not want to update all containers, just the ones having the image I am looking for, that is what SkipWhile is supposed to do.

Comment: It can't be sped up, you need to check all containers of all deployments anyway if you want to check each container's name with another string. So unless the client can perform a wildcard search, you simply need to wait until you obtained all metadata.

Comment: You can use Dictionary or other data structures that can like lookup that can help you check this :
deployment?.Spec?.Template?.Spec?.Containers.SkipWhile(x => !x.Image.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith(imageName.ToLowerInvariant()))

in average O(1) complexity time and then you can reduce to totally O(n)

Comment: @AnGG Can you post a solution?

Comment: @Mihaimyh but why `SkipWhile` and not `Where`?

Comment: You are true, I should have used `Where` instead of `SkipWhile`, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Mihaimyh also I would say that complexity (if we leave out handling of `updatedDeployments`) is `O(m*n)` and not `O(x^2)` and you can't do much better then that. One thing you can do better - use `HashSet` for `updatedDeployments` (if `V1Deployment` has overloaded `GetHashCode` and `Equals`) or just introduce some boolean flag `added` to track if you have already added current deployment to `updatedDeployments` (assuming deployments are unique).

Comment: Can you, please, explain why the complexity is `O(m*n)`, from what I understand 2 nested `foreach` loops means quadratic complexity.

Comment: n = deployment, m = containers in each deployment,

Comment: So is because `m` is part of `n`, that's understandable.

Comment: And if you do this only once you dont really need to manage data structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the comments, the worst-case time complexity really is `O(n^2)` where `n` is the length of `deployment`. But it's not because of the nested `foreach`; it's because of the call to `Contains`. Actually it's worse than that - the complexity is more precisely `O(m*n^2)`, where `m` is the number of containers per deployment, because the `Contains` is in the inner loop.

How about doing it like this (with complexity `O(m*n)`, which is optimal given the input data structures):

```
    private List<V1Deployment> UpdateImageTag(string imageName, string tag, List<V1Deployment> deployments)
    {
        if (deployments == null)
        {
            return new List<V1Deployment>();
        }

        var imageNameLower = imageName.ToLowerInvariant();

        var matches = deployments
            .Select(deployment => KeyValuePair.Create(
                deployment, 
                deployment.Spec?.Template?.Spec?.Containers
                    .Where(c => !c.Image.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith(imageNameLower))))
            .Where(kvp => kvp.Value != null)
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
            

        foreach (var container in matches.Values.SelectMany(x => x))
        {
            SetImageTag(tag, container);
        }

        return matches.Keys.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need dictionary here?  Just create a collection of value tuples.

Comment: Just to keep the example concise by being able to reference ``Keys`` and ``Values``. Of course it's not needed and it's slightly more efficient without, but doesn't change the complexity.

Comment: Without `.Where(kvp => kvp.Value != null && kvp.Value.Any())` there is a possibility to retun a non-null but empty `Dictionary`.